# Pytest how do i get the mark parameter inside a teardown method?

Tags: python, pytest

In my python module i have the following:

```
def setup_module(module):
    pass


def teardown_module(module):
    pass # i want myMarker parameter here

class TestClass:

    @pytest.mark.myMarker('how do i get this?')
    def test_simple(self):
        pass
```

How can i get the marker parameter to the teardown_module?

Answer (score 0):

Put the marker on the `class` and access it from the `module` parameter

```
def setup_module(module):
    pass


def teardown_module(module):
    mark = module.TestClass.pytestmark[0]
    print(mark) # Mark(name='myMarker', args=('how do I get this?',), kwargs={})


@pytest.mark.myMarker('how do I get this?')
class TestClass:

    def test_simple(self):
        pass
```

If you want it from the test you can add `requests` to it and assign it to a global variable, or use `self.test_simple` for more hardcoded solution without `requests`

```
mark = None


def setup_module(module):
    pass


def teardown_module(module):
    print(mark) # Mark(name='myMarker', args=('how do I get this?',), kwargs={})


class TestClass:

    @pytest.mark.myMarker('how do I get this?')
    def test_simple(self, request):
        global mark
        test = getattr(self, request.node.name)
        mark = test.pytestmark[0]
        # or
        mark = self.test_simple.pytestmark[0]
```